# How do you resample LDA in r?

Tags: r, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I thought that using bootstrap would resample my LDA but I am not sure. Additionally, if bootstrap does work, I am not sure how to code a bootstrap in r
Here is my LDA code:

```
library('MASS') 
n=nrow(iris)
train = sample(n ,size = floor(n*0.75), replace = F)
train.species =Species[train]
test.species=Species[-train]
lda.fit = lda(Species~. , data=iris, subset=train)
```

Comment: what library is lda from? also `replace = TRUE ` will allow you to do bootstrap sampling.

Comment: it is from the library MASS

Comment: I've taken to `modelr::bootstrap` lately, though [`caret::trainControl`](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#control) is very powerful if you like the ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

The code below uses `boot()` [library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) to perform bootstrap on `iris` dataset using [LDA](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/lda.html) to get the standard errors for the `LD1` and `LD2` coefficients. Also, initial part of the code shows LDA fitting without bootstrap with the same coefficients.

```
# Library
library(MASS)
library(boot)

# Get data
data(iris)
names(iris) <- gsub("\\.", "", names(iris)) #remove dots from column names

# Split data into train and test sets
train_index <-sample(seq(nrow(iris)),floor(dim(iris)[1]*0.75))
train <- iris[train_index,]
test <- iris[-train_index,]
test_Y <- test[, c('Species')]
test_X <- subset(test, select=-c(Species))

#### LDA without bootstrap: 
# Fit LDA to train data: 
lda.fit = lda(Species ~ . , data=train)
lda.fit
# Predict test_Y based on lda.fit above
lda.pred <- predict(lda.fit, test_X)
lda.class <- lda.pred$class
# Confusion matrix
table(lda.class, test_Y) 


#### LDA with bootstrap: 
# Fit LDA to train data: to get standard errors for coefficients
set.seed(1)
boot.fn <- function(data,index){ 
  return(coefficients(lda(Species ~ SepalLength + SepalWidth + PetalLength + PetalWidth, data=data, subset=index)))
}
# Call boot(): This returns LD1 and LD2 for each predictor
boot(train, boot.fn, 1000)
# NOTE: Here, in Bootstrap Statistics output, t1* to t4* are LD1 coefficients and t5* to t8* are LD2 coefficients
```